# How to make `lua executes cmd 'sudo' commands without manuly inputing passwd` possible?

Tags: lua, torch

I am training a mode using LuaTorch. Lately, I am faced with an annoying problem. The program runs more and more slowly as time goes by! When I execute

`sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3`

Then the program runs much faster. However, about one day after, it slows down again. I check the buffers and caches using `top`, finding they are quite high.

**The first question: Does that matters if I release the buffers and caches using that command when training a model?**
My initial idea is checking the time elapsed each epoch, and calls the cmd command when elapsed time is longer than the pre-setting value.

```
if time_elapse > time_out then
    os.execute('sudo sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3')
end
```

However,it requires your manuly inputs of passwd for the first time called. How to use lua code to avoid manuly code input?

Comment: You should find the problem in your code rather than doing some OS-level trickery.

Comment: `sudo` can read password from stdin: `echo 'password' | sudo -S command`

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question directly: permit your user to execute the `sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3` command without entering a password.

If a user named `naruto` is running your lua script, add the following line to `/etc/sudoers` (or better still, create a file in `/etc/sudoers.d` for it).

```
naruto ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3
```

This will allow `naruto` to execute the exact command as root without supplying a password.

As to the underlying problem, there's more here to look into.  You would never normally want to drop the page cache.  It's just a cache, and that memory isn't actually used.  Read through the very helpful page at http://www.linuxatemyram.com/, and in particular, consult the **Warning Signs** section at the end (see below, quoted from that page):

> **Warning signs** of a genuine low memory situation that you may want to
> look into:
>
> - available memory (or "free + buffers/cache") is close to zero swap
> - used increases or fluctuates
> - dmesg | grep oom-killer shows theOutOfMemory-killer at work

Answer (score 1):

The `sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3` is likely speeding up your process by forcing swapped pages back into main memory. This may mean your system is configured to swap too aggressively. You can configure swappiness by modifying `vm.swappiness`. Many Linux distros default this value to `60`. Try reducing it to `10` to encourage the kernel to keep your processes in memory. The [swappiness Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness) has more detailed instructions on modifying it. This doesn't answer your direct question, Mike nailed that, but it may help solve your underlying problem.